# Why am I not getting an sRGB default framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, color, glut, nvidia, srgb

I'm trying to make my OpenGL Haskell program gamma correct by making appropriate use of sRGB framebuffers and textures, but I'm running into issues making the default framebuffer sRGB.

Consider the following Haskell program, compiled for 32-bit Windows using GHC and linked against 32-bit freeglut:

```hs
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc(alloca)
import Foreign.Ptr(Ptr)
import Foreign.Storable(Storable, peek)
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.Raw
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLUT as GLUT
import Graphics.UI.GLUT(($=))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (_progName, _args) <- GLUT.getArgsAndInitialize
    GLUT.initialDisplayMode $= [GLUT.SRGBMode]
    _window <- GLUT.createWindow "sRGB Test"

    -- To prove that I actually have freeglut working correctly.
    -- This will fail at runtime under classic GLUT.
    GLUT.closeCallback $= Just (return ())

    glEnable gl_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB
    colorEncoding <- allocaOut $ glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv
        gl_FRAMEBUFFER gl_FRONT_LEFT gl_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_COLOR_ENCODING
    print colorEncoding

allocaOut :: Storable a => (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO a
allocaOut f = alloca $ \ptr -> do
    f ptr
    peek ptr
```

On my desktop (Windows 8 64-bit with a GeForce GTX 760 graphics card) this program outputs `9729`, a.k.a. `gl_LINEAR`, indicating that the default framebuffer is using linear color space, even though I explicitly requested an sRGB window. This is reflected in the rendering results of the actual program I'm trying to write - everything looks washed out because my linear color values aren't being converted to sRGB before being written to the framebuffer.

On the other hand, on my laptop (Windows 7 64-bit with an Intel graphics chip), the program prints `0` (huh?) and I get an sRGB default framebuffer *by default whether I request one or not!* And on both machines, if I manually create a non-default framebuffer bound to an sRGB texture, the program correctly prints `35904`, a.k.a. `gl_SRGB`.

Why am I getting different results on different hardware? Am I doing something wrong? How can I get an sRGB framebuffer consistently on all hardware and target OSes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured out enough details on this issue that I can "answer" it, although I'm not entirely happy with the results...

- The actual issue was inverted from what I thought was the case: my Nvidia-powered desktop was doing the sRGB conversions correctly, while my Intel-powered laptop was incorrectly outputting the linear color space values without converting them. I don't know why the default framebuffer on my desktop reports a `gl_LINEAR` color space even when an sRGB framebuffer is requested, but as long as I have `gl_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` turned on everything seems to display correctly.
- I ended up switching to GLFW for windowing, and it couldn't give me a working sRGB framebuffer on my laptop either. I think the issue may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386199/when-to-call-glenablegl-framebuffer-srgb), for which the answer was essentially "Intel drivers suck, don't trust anything they do".